# difference between object and nonobject types.?

Tags: objective-c, oop, object

What is difference between object and nonobject types.?I am talking in reference to Objective C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lol... this question is a troll-trap!

'Nonobject types' would likely refer to primitive types such as int, float and char. Objects are instances of classes, which can contain various different types and other objects.

A google search on ['difference between object and primitive](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=vss&source=hp&q=difference+between+object+and+primitive+data+type&pbx=1&oq=difference+between+object+and+primitive&aq=0v&aqi=g-v3&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=133471l140087l2l140960l41l15l1l22l22l0l253l2493l0.10.5l34l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=29e6033f7adbf144&biw=1280&bih=866)' would have yielded a lot of results on the topic. Also, you could search for ['what is an object in OOP](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=vss&source=hp&q=what+is+an+object+in+OOP&pbx=1&oq=what+is+an+object+in+OOP&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5493l9047l0l9442l25l16l0l3l3l0l207l1868l0.11.1l13l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=29e6033f7adbf144&biw=1280&bih=866)' or something to find out more about objects.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of Objective-C -- object types -- they are inherited from NSObject.
All other data -- primitive types (char, int, float etc) and structures are non-object types.